# Moose class as an attribute type?

Tags: perl, moose

Is there a way to constrain the value of an attribute to be a class name that inherits from some particular class?

```
has thing_class => (
  ??? => Some::Base::Class,
);
```

Here a valid value for `thing_class` should be `Some::Base::Class` or a class derived from it. `isa` is not the right thing to use, because that would require that the attribute be an instantiated instance of `Some::Base::Class`.

Answer (score 3):

Type constraints are imposed by `isa`. Of course, you'll need to define a suitable type constraint first.

```
use Moose::Util::TypeConstraints;

subtype 'FooBarSubclassName',
   as 'Str',
   where { $_->isa('Foo::Bar') };

no Moose::Util::TypeConstraints;


has thing_class => (
  isa => 'FooBarSubclassName',
);
```